# Why does Quicklisp fail to load log4cl on MacOS

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

On MacOS: When I try to load log4cl I get a compile error:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "log4cl")
To load "log4cl":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    log4cl
; Loading "log4cl"
.
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;   
;     Lock on package SB-C violated when interning LAMBDA-PARENT while in package
;     LOG4CL-IMPL.
;   See also:
;     The SBCL Manual, Node "Package Locks"
;   
;     (in form starting at line: 99, column: 0, position: 3779)

 COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while
compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "log4cl" "src" "naming-sbcl">
   [Condition of type UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR]
```

On Ubuntu: I do not see that error and log4cl loads without problem. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Log4cl is trying to access an implementation symbol named `sb-c::lambda-parent` but this symbol probably does not exist on your version of sbcl on MacOS, and as such Lisp is trying to add this symbol to the SB-C package; but since the package is locked, this is forbidden. Either `lambda-parent` used to exist and was removed (if your sbcl version is too recent), or the log4cl is recent and trying to access a symbol that is not present in a too old version of SBCL.

Comment: On MacOS I have version 2.3.3 of sbcl. On Ubuntu I have version 2.2.3. So it looks like log4cl does not compile on the new version of sbcl.

Comment: This comes from this commit from approx a month ago: https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/6a1416ed73017840141cfe5ed0c82ba8bb00fe81/  You should probably fill a bug for log4cl maintainers and in the meantime have a local patch to fix it

Comment: It looks like the issue has been fixed in log4cl: https://github.com/sharplispers/log4cl/commit/01242ffbc43f5cf17f612878666341b0a3430c46. So I guess I just have to work on Linux until log4cl is updated in quicklisp.

Comment: great, this is already fixed!, I propose you write a self-answer that summarizes the problem/solution and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said by [coredump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124319/coredump) :

> "Log4cl is trying to access an implementation symbol named
> sb-c::lambda-parent but this symbol probably does not exist on your
> version of sbcl on MacOS, and as such Lisp is trying to add this
> symbol to the SB-C package; but since the package is locked, this is
> forbidden."

And now I add my little two cents :

LAMBDA-PARENT has been [removed from SBCL 3 years ago](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/17c3ac2ff1a99b368d67390720c2df6bb8a857aa/), with the following message :

```
"Remove LAMBDA-PARENT.

LAMBDA-LEXENV already has it."
```

Now the question is : what is the version of your log4cl library, and where does it come from ?

Mine is coming from Quicklisp and it works fine with version 2.3.2 of SBCL, it is http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/log4cl/2021-12-09/log4cl-20211209-git.tgz

Maybe you should update [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) :

To get updated software, use:

```
(ql:update-dist "quicklisp")
```

Software updates are usually available about once per month.

To update the Quicklisp client, use:

```
(ql:update-client)
```

Comment: I also have the 20211209 version of log4cl which does not work with sbcl 2.3.3. So it seems that the problem occurs when upgrading from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it also does not work with SBCL 2.3.3 for me. Exact same error.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few solutions here, as confirmed by the comments:

- downgrade from SBCL 2.3.3 to 2.3.2
- patch the `sbcl-get-block-name` function in `.../quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/log4cl-20211209-git/src/naming-sbcl.lisp` with the function in this commit: https://github.com/sharplispers/log4cl/commit/01242ffbc43f5cf17f612878666341b0a3430c46?diff=split
- wait for a new quicklisp release, so the commit above is used when the library is installed: `(ql:quickload '(:log4cl))`

Answer (score 0):

I have SBCL 2.3.3 installed on GNU/Linux and had the same problem.

I solved the problem by using the version of `log4cl` from git:

```
$ cd quicklisp/local-projects/
$ git clone https://github.com/sharplispers/log4cl
```

Then running

```lisp
(ql:quickload "log4cl")
```

uses the local version which includes [the patch](https://github.com/sharplispers/log4cl/commit/01242ffbc43f5cf17f612878666341b0a3430c46) which fixes SBCL 2.3.3 compatibility.